# How can I identify which processes are using the GPU?

Tags: windows, nvidia-graphics-card, gpu, monitoring, opencl

Is there any way to find out which process is using the GPU for intensive calculations? (OpenCL, CUDA, etc? Primarily OpenCL?)

e.g. if you run an OpenCL-powered video transcoder, you'll see nothing in your task manager that tells your GPU is burning through data at a ridiculous rate - though your fans will have kicked into overdrive.

If the reply is driver-specific, I am interested in nVidia primarily.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Turns out Sysinternals' Process Explorer can do this (*of course* it can, there's nothing it can't do, apparently!).

[image: Process Explorer GPU load by process]

Comment: how can you tell if it is the dedicated gpu or the intel gpu?

Answer (score 8):

[Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), the open source alternative to Process Explorer, also shows the GPU usage.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to get the system information Window and click on the GPU Tab, so get a graph with the GPU usage.

[image]

Comment: By process or just total?

Comment: hover over the high spikes in the graph and you get a tooltip. But the tool also offers a GPU column.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Worked for me better than Process Explorer; Make sure you select all nodes there; after that you can add GPU usage column to the process list. Make sure you run it elevated.

Comment: Is this still the best resource?

Comment: @moondra ProcessHacker also allows you to add the GPU column to see which process use GPU. I prefer ProcessHacker because it is open source compared to Process Explorer.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded it. Going to fiddle around with it.

Comment: @moondra ok, also setup the plugins to have more functionality.

Answer (score 1):

AMD Catalyst Control Center has an indicator of GPU activity in the Performance section. I would assume nVidia software has a similar output. It's usually associated with overclocking.

[image]

Otherwise you can download the free [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/). It includes a GPU Load output.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but you misunderstand my question - I need to identify the *process* responsible for the GPU load.

Comment: Ah relied more on the title. I'm going to edit it to be more clear.